# Get seconds from the day to Thursday 10:00 at that week

Tags: ruby, time

How do I get the seconds from the day to Thursday 10:00 at that week? If later than Thursday 10:00, I want to get zero. For example:

```
seconds = (Thursday 10:00) - Time.now
```

Comment: When does a week start/end? I hope you are not a nationalist, believing that whatever day that you have in mind as the start of a week holds over to the entire world.

Comment: Forgive my bad English

Comment: You didn't seem to get my point. At least to my knowledge, there are countries/areas in which a week starts on Monday. There are also countries/areas in which a week starts on Sunday. I am not sure if there are other starts of a week.

Comment: oh, a week starts on Monday

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Chronic](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic/):

```
require 'chronic'

Chronic.parse('this Thursday at 10:00 am') - Time.now

#=> 98688.251918432
```

Comment: Thanks, you know what I mean

Comment: @pangpang - If that answer was indeed what you were searching for, could you please consider marking it as correct?

Answer (score 2):

You can subtract two time to get difference in seconds ([see docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Time.html#method-i-2D)):

```
require 'time'
Time.parse(end_time) - Time.parse(time)
# => 57600.0
```

**Update**

To calculate difference between two time getting two fixed time is an absolute must. You can get time for next week simply by adding numeric time difference in seconds to existing time. Here:

```
next_week_time = Time.parse(end_time) + (1*7*24*60*60)
```

Or if you are on Rails, with ActiveSupport you can simply do:

```
next_week_time = Time.parse(end_time) + 1.weeks
```

Comment: sorry, the end_time is not fixed

Comment: can you explain further? What do you mean by `end_time` is not fixed?

Answer (score 0):

`(4-Time.now.wday-1)*24*3600`: get the number of days from the day morning to Thursday of the week.

`Time.now.seconds_until_end_of_day`: get the rest seconds of the day.

```
seconds = (4-Time.now.wday-1)*24*3600 + Time.now.seconds_until_end_of_day + 10*3600
seconds = seconds > 0 ? seconds : 0
```

Comment: This code works but you provide no explanation as to what it's doing or how it works. It's just a code drop. An explanation/walkthrough of your code would make the answer better.